# Buscar un digito en una columna y añadir una palabra en otra

Tags: r, regex

Tengo el siguiente df

```
datos2<-data.frame(
  col1=c("rojo","rojo","verde","rojo","verde","rojo"),
  col2=c(123,234,222,111,456,345),
  col3=c("Esp 1",NA,NA,NA,"Psp 4",NA)
)
```

```
   col1 col2  col3
1  rojo  123 Esp 1
2  rojo  234  <NA>
3 verde  222  <NA>
4  rojo  111  <NA>
5 verde  456 Psp 4
6  rojo  345  <NA>
```

Quiero añadir a la col3 la palabra Esp seguido del primer digito de la col2 solo si la col1 es rojo

Algo asi como

```
ifelse(datos2$col1 =="rojo" & grepl("(\\d{1})", datos2$col2)....añadir Esp \\1 a la col3
```

El resultado buscado es el siguiente:

```
  col1 col2  col3
1  rojo  123 Esp 1
2  rojo  234 Esp 2
3 verde  222  <NA>
4  rojo  111 Esp 1
5 verde  456 Psp 4
6  rojo  345 Esp 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre que no necesites nada con el valor actual de `col3` podrías implementar algo así:

```
rojos <- datos2$col1 == "rojo"
datos2$col3[rojos] <- gsub("(\\d{1}).*", "Esp \\1", datos2$col2[rojos])
datos2
```

Detalle:

- Generamos un vector de lógicos con las filas dónde `col1 == "rojo"` el cual usaremos para seleccionar dónde haremos los cambios
- Con `gsub("(\\d{1}).*", "Esp \\1", datos2$col2[rojos])`, capturamos el primer dígito de `Col2` y lo usmos para el nuevo patrón de `col3`.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurrió el siguiente código que resuelve tu problema

1. Recorre el dataframe
2. Preguntas si en la primera columna existe la palabra "rojo"
3. Si existe, obtienes el dato de la columna 2 y obtiene la primera palabra, para esto puedes usar substr
4. Concatenas "esp" con el primer digito utilizando la función paste.

```
for( currentRow in 1:nrow(datos2)){
  
  if(datos2[currentRow,1] == "rojo"){
    numero = datos2[currentRow,2]
    datos2[currentRow,3] <- paste("Esp",substr(numero,start=1,stop=1))
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva,
Saludos